# Git switching branch

Tags: git, branch

There is something I don't get yet with Git. It is branching.

So let’s say that I have a local repository `A` which I clone from a remote one `B`.
So now `A` have the *master* branch checked out.

So when I push from `A` it goes to `B` *master*.

`B` is just a clone on [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), a clone of `C`.

From time to time, in order to get in sync, I pull from the `C` master branch.

But now the `C` master branch is quite broken for the time being.
Since from `A` I had pull from `C`, my local `A` is also buggy.

So I would like from `A` to pull the `C` stable branch.
How can I do it in this situation?

Do you create a new branch on `A` and pull from `C`? But since `A` has the `C` master change, I need to revert it first...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
git fetch C
git checkout C/stable-branch
git checkout -b myCopy
```

Then `myCopy` is a local (copied) branch of C's stable one.

Answer (score 7):

In two lines:
`git fetch C`
`git checkout -b myCopy -t C/stable-branch`

**myCopy** is now a local branch of **C/stable-branch**, and is tracking it, so you can do `git push` and `git pull` without a refspec.