# How to switch a branch using GitHub Shell

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am having an issue with my GitLab Repository. Somehow there is a conflict between my local repo and the remote one. GitHub Desktop says `Commit is not successful because there is a conflict and refer to Shell`. When I open the GitHub Shell to find out which file is causing the issue, it appears that I am in `Master` branch and I am sure enough that I shouldn't be in the Master branch. So how can I come to my own branch and how can I find out which file is causing the conflict? It also complains about pslxml file that I am not aware of at all. [image]

Comment: Please consider doing a search before posting questions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826779/git-switching-branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mike. You don't have to use GitShell if yo a not comfortable with it. In case of GitHub desktop always do a sync to you local branch before you perform a commit. This way at least your local branch will always be parallel to the remote one.Once you are done with that, then you update you local branch from the b

Answer (score 1):

to make a new branch and to switch to it..

```
git checkout -b yourNewBranchName
```

to just switch to a new branch the same but without the `-b`

Answer (score 1):

To list your local branches:

```
git branch
```

To switch to a local branch:

```
git checkout branchName
```

*`.ps1xml` files are configuration .xmls for WindowsPowerShell. 
Looking at the error message you might have added those files listed in the shell to your `.gitignore`, hence your git does not find them and it throws an error. Double check your `.gitignore`

Comment: git branch doesn't do anything in my case. It says in the same directory master. It doesn't show list of branches to choose from.

Comment: `git branch` always outputs _something_ 
If it only lists master then that's the only branch you have on your local repo. Did you do a `git pull` before trying to commit? Maybe that will resolve your conflicts.

Comment: The issue has been resolved already and I did it using GitHub desktop. While using the git branch command it stayed on the same directory and the funny thing is that it shouldn't show me the master branch at all because of the fact that we commit all the changes to the master at the end meaning once everything has gone to the production. I am not sure but something went wrong due to which my local branch became the master.